# Expo cannot open development build on android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, simulator

I'm trying to run my Expo managed project on Android simulator with `npx expo run:android`.

I have `expo-dev-client` installed.

When I run `npx expo run:android`, it fails with the message:

```
CommandError: Couldn't open Android app with activity "com.my.app.name://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.13%3A8081" on device "Pixel_4".
The app might not be installed, try installing it with: npx expo run:android -d Pixel_4
```

I ran `npx expo run:android -d Pixel_4` as suggested in the above error message only to get the exact same error message as above.

On the emulator, I was able to confirm that the development build is installed.

However, the Expo CLI apparently cannot open the app.

Could someone guide me to the right direction to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the reported issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22210.

This worked for me: `npx expo start` then Press `a` for android.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is described here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23440

If the package name for android in app.json has underscore (i.e. com.example.with_underscore) it will throw that error.